# Give input parameter of stored procedure from file

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with 3 parameters,and I think I am not doing right the first parameter of my stored procedure.

```
string path = @"D:\test2";
var ngd = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt").Select(file => File.ReadAllLines(file)).FirstOrDefault();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password="))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SaveData", connection))
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@request_xml", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 999999).Value = ngd;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ST", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = MachineName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SN", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = listBoxItem;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Good");
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verification failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

I ran my stored procedure in SQL and everything worked fine,I ran a different procedure that needs only the `@ST`,`@SN` and it worked but now in this procedure where I give the `request_xml` as

```
var ngd = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt").Select(file => File.ReadAllLines(file)).FirstOrDefault();
```

it's not working...

My question is,should I store the data from the file differently in a variable?Is there a "correct way" to store the file in a variable that can be used by the input parameter ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the sored procedure?

Comment: @DDDSoft - see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ReadAllLines` which returns an `array` of `string` with each element being a line from the file.

so in the line below you are actually passing a `string[]` rather than a `string`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@request_xml", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 999999).Value = ngd;
```

You should use `ReadAllText` instead, which returns a single `string`

```
var ngd = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt").Select(file => File.ReadAllText(file)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanations :)